# Calling Post request without body in java

Tags: java, api, rest, web-services, httpurlconnection

I have a post API which doesn't accept any input. I have to get output from API. But it is giving compilation error.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
String targetUrl="https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/"+BotID+"/dynamicEntities/"+dynamicEntityId+"/pushRequests
URL url = new URL(targetUrl);
connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setUseCaches (false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic aWRjcy1vZGEtOTQxN2Y5MzU2MGI5NGViOGEyZTJhNGM5YWFjOWEzZmYtdDBfQVBQSUQ6MjQ0YWU4ZTItNmY3MS00YWYyLWI1Y2MtOTExMDg5MGQxNDU2");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");    
**osw.write();**   //this line is expecting input in parameter
osw.flush();
osw.close();
os.close(); 
connection.connect();
```

If I dont pass any value in `osw.write()` it gives compilation error. How can I resolve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following method for the post call. You will need to add the outputstream to the `osw.write()` as it expects a parameter.

```
private static void sendPOST() throws IOException {
    URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    // For POST only - START
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    // For POST only - END

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        } 
    else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
    }
}
```

For more details on the above code look [here](https://www.journaldev.com/7148/java-httpurlconnection-example-java-http-request-get-post).

Comment: thank you @Pritam . this might work for me. what is POST_PARAM here. it is giving compilation error. is it some constant? I do not have any parameter for this API.

Comment: Since you don't have any post parameter you can just remove anything related to `POST_PARAM`. For `write()` method look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

Comment: thank you Pritam. write() accepts the parameter so i declared a string . String data=""; and then pass data into write(data). without passing anything it was giving compilation error.